# is there any way to change the users host in my sql

Tags: mysql

I am building a mysql server to allow a user to only access the database if he is on an internal ip address.

```
SET PASSWORD  FOR 'testuser'@'MyIPwillgohere' = PASSWORD('password');
```

but i get the following error while using the above statement

```
 Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

I think it has something to do with the host being % instead of local host or my ip address.

```
+------------------+-------------+
| user             | host        |
+------------------+-------------+
| testuser         | %           |
| root             | 127.0.0.1   |
| root             | ::1         |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost   |
| root             | localhost   |
| root             | raspberrypi |
+------------------+-------------+
```

How can i change the host or what should i do to fix this issue. I am using putty SSH connection to connect to the server and running mysql as the root user.

The question is how to change the test users host maybe?

I want to change the host from % to either local host or maybe my own ip address. I have used workbench to log in as editor but the host is still the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the soloution to my own problem. It didnt let me change the where the host was connecting to by changing the password EG

> You might try something like this (but note that DROP essentially
>   means "DELETE" so be careful):
>
> DROP USER 'testuser'; GRANT USAGE ON dbnamegoeshere.* to
>   'testuser@MyIPwillgohere' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

Doing that it said there was no match found. I hand to grant the privileges to the user first and state where he is connecting from and then changing the password was allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this (but note that `DROP` essentially means "`DELETE`" so be careful):

```
DROP USER 'testuser';
GRANT USAGE ON dbnamegoeshere.* to 'testuser@MyIPwillgohere' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```